# QGIS based rules symbology with boolean options

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, rule-based, boolean

I have a point layer with some boolean fields. I have created a symbol for each field when it is true.
[image]

However, when I create new symbologies for combined cases with more then one field true, I obtain stacked individual symbols.

For example, the expression rule:
`"branch"=true AND "derivation"=true` (with a new symbol)
so this symbol is stacked with each true individual symbol.

How to disable individual symbols and keep only the new symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the non combined cases, add a second condition to exclude the cases that should not match (mutually exclusive groups):

1. `"branch"=true AND "derivation" <> true` -> shows results only for branch=true where derivation = false
2. `"derivation"=true AND "branch" <> true` -> shows results only for derivation=true where branch = false
3. `"branch"=true AND "derivation"=true` -> shows results only for cases where branch and derivation are true

Comment: Many thanks Babel for your prompt response. It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In this case probably easier than using rule based style is to choose the Single Symbol Style and use data driven override to choose the SVG symbol. Advantage: you have to write just one expression. Using `case()` condition makes it easy to first get the features with both conditions fulfilled, than these cases are excluded from the further evalution:

```
case 
when "branch"=true AND "derivation"=true
then  '[svg_path_1]'
when "branch"=true AND "derivation" <> true
then '[svg_path_2]'
when "derivation"=true AND "branch" <> true
then '[svg_path_3]'
end
```

Replace `[svg_path_1/2/3]` with the actual path to the svg symbol, e.g. to one of the pre-installed symbols in QGIS installation path like in my case: `C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./svg//crosses/Cross6.svg`

[image]

Comment: Interesting take, I've never considered this, but what happens with your legend in the layouts?

Comment: Good point: indeed, the legend shows only one of the symbols, the one defined as default.